# Download an .xlsx file using GetUrl()

Tags: r, rcurl, geturl

I am trying to download a .xlsx file using the RCurl library and GetUrl() function.

But i get the error 
embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\024\0\006\0\b\0\0\0!\0ª÷X¤z\001\0\0\024\006\0\0\023\0\b\002[Content_Types].xml ¢\004\002( \0\002\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\'

Is there anyway to handle this? The same call works perfectly fine for .csv file formats.

Any Help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the code used?

Comment: `download.file` with `method = 'curl'` is usually sufficient. Or some Excel-reading functions can handle the connection directly, e.g. `openxlsx::read.xlsx('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00242/ENB2012_data.xlsx')`

Comment: or, y'know, you cld `readxl::read_excel("EXCEL_URL")` and be done with it

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that this is a binary file, see documentation:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RCurl/versions/1.95-4.8/topics/getURL

The reason is that xslx is a binary format, while csv is just text.